# Chrome pdf viewer left/right arrow key does not work

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, pdf

When i open a PDF using the built-in Chrome pdf viewer, i can usually jump to next/previous page just by using the right/left arrow key.

This suddenly stopped working for me, and pressing the right/left arrow key has no effect, while I can still navigate up and down the page using up/down arrow keys normally.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This suddenly happened to me as well.  Odd that you asked this just 5 hours ago.  Did a recent Chrome update break this?

Comment: That's my best guess. Just like Mike mentioned in his answer Chrome is not supposed to implement this functionality, but it was working for me for months, just until yesterday.

Comment: FWIW, this is working for me again now.  Same for you?

Comment: Nope, it's still not working here

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by update to Chrome 41 and above. Temporary solution is to copy older pdf.dll library from Chrome <= 40. Its mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/889197/chrome-change-page-navigation-keys-in-pdf-viewer).

If you are lucky as me - you can still find the old `pdf.dll` in your Program Files
ie. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\40.0.2214.115\pdf.dll`

md5 checksum: `8b56fcfcb0f84733070d97d39fbcd2f6`

After you copy it to the newer Chrome directory (+ restart Chrome), PDF arrow-keys work again.

Comment: zbycz, Can you upload the correct pdf.dll to some online internet site?

Comment: Fixed in Chrome 42  (april 2015) - bug  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455902 cr  https://codereview.chromium.org/959443003/ commit  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7593306a8770d5fd7d884532a6dd012df55b4d7f

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this functionality is not implemented in Chrome browser yet. This navigation may work in Adobe Reader and I'm not sure if it works the same way in Google Drive but not in Chrome's native PDF viewer. It may be handy for you to use Page Up and Page Down keys.

Comment: It was implemented in the builtin pdf viewer of chrome (pdfium) at 40 and earlier. Page Up and Page Down works for scrolling, but they don't align start of page with top of the screen. With arrow keys I can work with pdf like with book - single key press gives me whole new page (very comfortable for 100+ page pdf presentations); and PgUp/PgDown are like rolling the (vertical) scroll of papyrus with several keypresses to align every new page.